# Python Base64 Decode Exception in Server

Tags: python, base64, aes, google-cloud-platform

I'm using the Cipher model below: (I found it from StackOverflow)

```
class AESCipher(object):

    def __init__(self, key): 
        self.bs = 32
        self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        raw = self._pad(raw)
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:AES.block_size]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return self._unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[AES.block_size:])).decode('utf-8')

    def _pad(self, s):
        return s + (self.bs - len(s) % self.bs) * chr(self.bs - len(s) % self.bs)

    @staticmethod
    def _unpad(s):
        return s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]
```

In local everything is fine but when i deploy to Google Cloud i get this error:

```
File "/app/app/models.py", line 108, in decrypt
   enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/base64.py", line 90, in b64decode
   return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Comment: This is unrelated to the encryption part. The `Incorrect padding` error refers to the padding in the base64 encoding, i.e. the trailing one or two `=`, `==`. The `b64decode` function should be able to decode the output of a previous `b64encode` call. It would seem very likely to me that the problem is not with code you posted, but with the code that calls these functions. I.e. some corruption of the base64 encoded string happens somewhere before the decryption method is called. I don't think the question can be answered without seeing that part of the code.